# setTimeout of a forEach loop with datetime countdown?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, settimeout

I'm trying to create a script that loops through an array of html elements, and creates a countdown for each of them, using a `setTimeout`. I don't really know why this does not work, but here is my code, and the console.log it gives me.
Console log >

```
-1481055605166  testing.html:61:5
End  testing.html:64:5
days-> -17142-hours->-21-minutes->-21-second->-6  testing.html:75:5
NaN  testing.html:61:5
days-> NaN-hours->NaN-minutes->NaN-second->NaN  testing.html:75:5
NaN  testing.html:61:5
days-> NaN-hours->NaN-minutes->NaN-second->NaN*
```

Here is the code >

```js
  var productos = document.querySelectorAll(".producto.med");

  function recorrido() {
    productos.forEach(function(item) {
      var hora = item.querySelector("#hasta");
      cdtd(hora);
    });
  }
  var timer = setTimeout(recorrido, 2000);

  function cdtd(dia) {
    var xmas = new Date(dia);
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = xmas.getTime() - now.getTime();
    console.log(timeDiff);
    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      console.log("End");
      // Run any code needed for countdown completion here
    }
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;
    var total = 'days-> ' + days + '-hours->' + hours + '-minutes->' + minutes + '-second->' + seconds;
    console.log(total);
  }
```

```html
<article class="producto med" id='{{$producto->id}}'>
  <h4>uno</h4>
  <div class="img-producto">
    <img src="{{$producto->ruta_imagen}}" alt="producto">
  </div>
  <div class="datos-producto">
    <ul class="tiempo">
      <li>desde: <span>{{$producto->fecha_inicio}}</span>
      </li>
      <li>hasta: <span id="hasta1">2016-12-12 15:45:00</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="restante">tiempo restante:</p>
    <p class="tiempo">12hs 43m 03s</p>//JS PARA COUNTDOWNL
  </div>
  <a href="" class="ofertar">Ofertar ahora</a>
</article>
<article class="producto med" id='{{$producto->id}}'>
  <h4>dos</h4>
  <div class="img-producto">
    <img src="{{$producto->ruta_imagen}}" alt="producto">
  </div>
  <div class="datos-producto">
    <ul class="tiempo">
      <li>desde: <span>{{$producto->fecha_inicio}}</span>
      </li>
      <li>hasta: <span id="hasta">2017-12-12 15:45:00</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="restante">tiempo restante:</p>
    <p class="tiempo">12hs 43m 03s</p>//JS PARA COUNTDOWNL
  </div>
  <a href="" class="ofertar">Ofertar ahora</a>
</article>
<article class="producto med" id='{{$producto->id}}'>
  <h4>tres</h4>
  <div class="img-producto">
    <img src="{{$producto->ruta_imagen}}" alt="producto">
  </div>
  <div class="datos-producto">
    <ul class="tiempo">
      <li>desde: <span>{{$producto->fecha_inicio}}</span>
      </li>
      <li>hasta: <span id="hasta">2016-12-12 15:45:00</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="restante">tiempo restante:</p>
    <p class="tiempo">12hs 43m 03s</p>//JS PARA COUNTDOWNL
  </div>
  <a href="" class="ofertar">Ofertar ahora</a>
</article>
```

Comment: don't use ununique id elements, use classes for selectors

Comment: `cdtd(hora)`, where `hora` is `HTMLElement` and then `new Date(HTMLElement)`...

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/12562091/215552 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/13729482/215552

Answer (score 1):

1. The first product has a "hasta1" for id value. This should be "`hasta`"
2. HTML elements should have unique ids.
   This can be achieved by

a) Using "data-id" attributes instead of "id" attributes, changing all

```
    <span id="hasta">
```

into

```
    <span data-id="hasta">
```

b) Make the selector find these elements by changing

```
       var hora = item.querySelector("#hasta");
```

to

```
       var hora = item.querySelector("[data-id=hasta]");
```

3. The `Nan` values indicate the data value used for Date is invalid: this is because an HTMLSpan element is being passed to `cdtd`, not a string. One way to fix this is to add a statement at the beginning of `cdtd`

   ```
     function cdtd(dia) {

      // get text before creating date

         dia = dia.textContent || dia.innerText;       
         var xmas = new Date(dia);

      // ... and continue
   ```
4. Changing `setTimeout` to `setInterval`, as in

   ```
   var timer = setInterval(recorrido, 2000);
   ```

should repeatedly call `recorrido` until the timer is stopped in `cdtd` (not tested). Stopping the timer can use `clearInterval` for clarity, although calling `clearTimeout` does the same thing as `clearInterval`.

---

**Update:** Warning: avoid using class selectors to find elements if the class name is also used for styling. Use of data attributes provide an alternative.

In this example, both `<ul class="tiempo">` and `<p class="tiempo">` match a selector for `.tiempo`. If elements with this class name have their content set to show the time remaining, the list element will be updated first and destroy  the child element with the `data-id="hasta"` attribute. This produces a `dia` value of `null`.

Comment: Nice. 4. setTimeout from the question title should be called at the end of `recorrido`, not `cdtd`.

Comment: @vp_arth Thanks for the feedback. Looks as if `setInterval` could be used instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: hey it work the first time, but then it tells me that dia is null, i mean, the first run of the function works correctly but then dia is null

Comment: `dia == null` means `item.querySelector("[data-id=hasta]");` found no elements. I was unable to reproduce the error. Calling recorrido after 2 seconds and after 4 seconds did not throw an exception. I did not, however,  compile or expand the HTML template code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are looking for something listed in the page: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript.html#fbid=S_-Ojf9buFk

> As long as you can calculate the number of milliseconds in an
>   interval, you can come up with a number by dividing the total number
>   of milliseconds by the number of milliseconds in the desired interval.
>   What's more, we can apply the modulus (%) operator to strip out that
>   value to determine the next larger interval. The key is to always go
>   from the smallest interval - milliseconds - to the largest - days:

```
Date.daysBetween = function( date1, date2 ) {
  //Get 1 day in milliseconds
  var one_day=1000*60*60*24;

  // Convert both dates to milliseconds
  var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
  var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

  // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
  var difference_ms = date2_ms - date1_ms;
  //take out milliseconds
  difference_ms = difference_ms/1000;
  var seconds = Math.floor(difference_ms % 60);
  difference_ms = difference_ms/60; 
  var minutes = Math.floor(difference_ms % 60);
  difference_ms = difference_ms/60; 
  var hours = Math.floor(difference_ms % 24);  
  var days = Math.floor(difference_ms/24);

  return days + ' days, ' + hours + ' hours, ' + minutes + ' minutes, and ' + seconds + ' seconds';
}
```